# Display hours per hour in GraphView?

Tags: android, datetime, android-graphview

Using the GraphView library i found this part of code:

```
/*
         * use Date as x axis label
         */
        long now = new Date().getTime();
        data = new GraphViewData[size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            data[i] = new GraphViewData(now+(i*60*60*24*1000), rand.nextInt(20)); // next day
        }
        exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(data);

        if (getIntent().getStringExtra("type").equals("bar")) {
            graphView = new BarGraphView(
                    this
                    , "GraphViewDemo"
            );
        } else {
            graphView = new LineGraphView(
                    this
                    , "GraphViewDemo"
            );
            ((LineGraphView) graphView).setDrawBackground(true);
        }
        graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data
```

That displays the date like "Sept 16, Sept 20" Ect etc... Is there possible change this code and display hour per hour? Like "06.00, 07.00, 08.00" etc etc?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for date formatting:

```
SimpleDateFormat hoursDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h.mm");

for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    data[i] = new GraphViewData(hoursDateFormat.format(now+(i*60*60*24*1000)), rand.nextInt(20)); // next day
    }
```

Comment: Do you think is possible write both thing? I mean Display on X axis (Sept 16 10.00, Sept 16 11.00 etc etc)? always using that code

Comment: Yes, all you need is to change hoursDateFormat value to "MMM DD h.mm"

Comment: Sorry `unknown entity`

Comment: Ok, wait now it works..but it displays (Aug28 11.29, Sept 6 11.29 and Sept 11 11.29) not day by day and hour by hour

Comment: I wrote `for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    data[i] = new GraphViewData((now+(i*60*60*24*100)), rand.nextInt(20)); // next day
    }` and `SimpleDateFormat hoursDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd h.mm");` and now writing `100` instead `1000` (i don't know what is this value) it displays Aug28 11.57 Aug30 09.05

Comment: new Date().getTime() returns time in milliseconds.You should use 1000 to get correct calculations, 1000 - is number of milliseconds in 1 second. Can you show your complete code snippet?

Comment: Here there is my real problem and what i would do and the complete code of graph http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481886/battery-graph-in-android-using-graphview-library

Comment: sorry but i don't follow you.. Where have i to put ti code?`ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: I use older version of GraphView without CustomLabelFormatter setter:
ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d h.mm");
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    labels.add(hoursDateFormat.format(now + (i*60*60*24*1000)));
}
//axe X labels
graphView.setHorizontalLabels(labels.toArray(new String[labels.size()]));